# What's the best way to handle multiple like-named files in emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp

One problem that I have with emacs is that it doesn't seem to handle like-named files in different directories very well.  For example, if I'm not careful, I'll end up with 20 `__init__.py` buffers open.  What I've been doing is using `M-x rename-buffer` and renaming it to indicate what package it's within.  However, doing this manually is somewhat tedious.

Does anyone have any strategies for attacking this problem?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I like [uniquify](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Uniquify.html), which comes with Emacs:

```
(require 'uniquify)

(setq uniquify-buffer-name-style 'reverse)
(setq uniquify-separator "/")
(setq uniquify-after-kill-buffer-p t) ; rename after killing uniquified

(setq uniquify-ignore-buffers-re "^\\*") ; don't muck with special buffers (or Gnus mail buffers)
```

With those settings, the directory gets added to the buffer name, giving you an indication of *where* the file is.  For example, loading the files `/some/path/to/Makefile` and `/some/path/to/different/Makefile` would result in the following buffer names:

```
Makefile/to           (which is /some/path/to/Makefile)
```

and

```
Makefile/different    (which is /some/path/to/different/Makefile)
```

`uniquify` also handles updating the buffer names when buffers are deleted, so when one of the two `Makefile` buffers is deleted, the other gets renamed to simply `Makefile`.

Comment: And it comes with Emacs Starter Kit by default.

Comment: You mean Emacs Starter Kit enables it by default?  Because it's shipped with Emacs itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you want full control you can redefine `create-file-buffer`.

If you want the full filename it could be as simple as

```
(defun create-file-buffer (filename)
  "Create a suitably named buffer for visiting FILENAME, and return it."
  (generate-new-buffer filename))
```

See `files.el` for reference.

Comment: It's not a wise thing to redefine a standard library function. Better advise it how uniquify does.